# How to make it so that when money comes to the Metamask wallet, they are automatically redirected to this smart contract?

Tags: solidity, transactions, addresses, accounts, balances

I wrote a smart contract on Solidity, which, when receiving money to its address, redirects 50% to the first wallet, 25% to the second wallet.

How to make it so that when money comes to the Metamask wallet, they are automatically redirected to this smart contract? (And then this smart contract will distribute them to the two necessary wallets).

P.S.
Please review the code, check it for safety and correctness. If something is not written correctly, please tell me how to rewrite it correctly. I am new to Solidity
Thanks for attention.

Smart Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Demo {
        constructor() payable{}
        receive() external payable{}

        

        address addr1 = 0x583031D1113aD414F02576BD6afaBfb302140225;
        address addr2 = 0xdD870fA1b7C4700F2BD7f44238821C26f7392148;

        function withdrawFunds() external {
            //address target = payable(_to);
            address payable wallet1 = payable(addr1);
            address payable wallet2 = payable(addr2);

            uint _50 = address(this).balance/100*50; //50% of balance of contract
            uint _25 = address(this).balance/100*25; //25% of balance of contract

            wallet1.transfer(_50);
            wallet2.transfer(_25);
        }

        function receiveFunds() external payable {
            this.withdrawFunds();
        }

        function getBalance() public view returns(uint){
            return address(this).balance;
        }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to do it onchain, you can write a kind of bot using web3.js or ethers.js for example that reads continuously your balance, and trigger transaction for you.

Comment: And where to place a bot written in web3js?
Did I understand correctly that this is a web application and this bot needs to be uploaded to the hosting as a regular site?